# Searching the * in a string and replace it through nothing

Tags: java, string, char

I have a homework to do and have a problem. I have to search the "*" (star) in a string in Java (I work with Eclipse IDE) and have to delete it, but somehow my Code does not work.

```java
class Main {

    public static String starOut(String s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == '*') {
                s.replace(s.charAt(i), '');

            }
        }

        return s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result = starOut("ab*cd");
        System.out.println(result); // => "ad"
        System.out.println(starOut("ab**cd")); // => "ad"
        System.out.println(starOut("sm*eilly")); // => "silly"
    }
}
```

The output should be like in the comments in the last lines

Answer (score 4):

Your code doesn't even compile, there is no empty `char` for `''`. I would use a `StringBuilder`, start with an empty `StringBuilder` and add all `char`(s) that are not `*` to it. Then return that as a `String`. Like,

```
public static String starOut(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        if (ch != '*') {
            sb.append(ch);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Alternatively, if you **can** use in-built methods;

```
public static String starOut(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("\\*", "");
}
```

Comment: Or even `return s.replace("*", "")` which doesn't use regex syntax so no escaping of `*` is needed.